# Ajax Unobtrusive not working when posting from rendered partial view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a multi step form, when user can go back and forth answering questions.
At first step I upload files to the server and everything works fine. But when user click on "go back" button, change some files (or not), and click on "next", I received this message on console:
"Empty string passed to getElementById()" at jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js.

And the form is not posted like before.

Here's my form:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginRouteForm("FileUpload", new { controller = "FileUpload", action = "UploadMultipleFiles" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { id = "currentStepForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { //... code here }
```

I'm posting from another partial view where buttons "go back" and "next" are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    currentStepForm_OnSubmit();

        function onNextStep() {       
            $('#currentStepForm').submit();
        }

        function currentStepForm_OnSubmit() {
            $('#currentStepForm')
                .submit(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();

                    $('#divCustomMessage').css('display', 'none');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        type: $(this).attr('method'),
                        data: new FormData(this),
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        beforeSend: function (XHR) {
                            //$('.loading').show();
                        }
                    }).done(function (result) {
                        if (result == 'Sucesso') {
                            goTo_NextStep();
                        } else {
                            handleErrorResponse(result);                        
                        }
                    });
                });
        }

        function goTo_NextStep() {
            $.get("/ActivationStep/OnStepNextChanged", function (data) {
                $('#stepRender').html(data);
                refreshCurrentStep();
            })
            .fail(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you have `Ajax.BeginRouteForm()` when all you do is cancel it and submit the form view ajax?

Comment: I need action and method attributes, because the way I call is common for all form steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out why.

Needed to call "currentStepForm_OnSubmit();" after ajax done.
So my next call could be intercepted.